# Incorrect diff with multiple peer reviewed edits

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, suggested-edits, diff

If you take a look at edit number 2 and 3 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5408754/revisions), you will notice notice that a change has been made that does not appear in the diffs.

I edited this post twice in a short period of time. Both times I took a link out of the pre tag that they were formerly in.

Only my second changes in noted in the diff, and the first change "appears" to come out of nowhere. (ie, the php.ini line changes with no apparent owner to the change)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in your first change, you didn't alter the *text*. If the rendered-HTML diff in the revision history were to highlight this, it would appear that you'd replaced one line of text with... an identical line of text.

If you look at [your original suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/22218) and switch to the Markdown diff, you'll see both changes.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll accept that.

Answer (score 1):

Our improved diff engine is now much stricter about what it considers "different", so (as you can see), your change is now indeed visible.